# clearInterval isn'tworking

Tags: javascript, jquery, clearinterval

I have to clear the interval but I don't know why it isn't working. Normally it schould be quite simple, but I just can't find out whats wrong.

```
if(data.groupStandings[0].active === true){
  Tabelle();
  var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  if(data.groupStandings[0].active === false){
    clearInterval(timerId);
  }
  var timeLeft = 5;       
  function countdown() {
    if (timeLeft < 0) {
      clearTimeout(timerId);
      code();
      timeLeft--;
      if(timeLeft <= -5){
        timeLeft = 5;
      }
    } else {
      code();
      timeLeft--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to clear the interval *immediately* after setting it?  Why not just not set it in the first place?  Additionally, under what conditions do you ever expect `data.groupStandings[0].active === true` and `data.groupStandings[0].active === false` to *both* be true?

Comment: You only enter this block if `active === true` and only cancel the interval if `active === false`?

Comment: `clearTimeout` should be `clearInterval`.

Answer (score 0):

You're entering the case when

```
data.groupStandings[0].active === true
```

but trying to clear the interval on the value being false

```
var timerId = setInterval(countdown, 1000);

if (data.groupStandings[0].active === false) { // here
    clearInterval(timerId);
}
```

so content of the `if` block will not be read at all unless `data.groupStandings[0].active` somehow changes it's state (which is not seen in the code)

Comment: I tryed it with an else if but it still won't work how can I fix this?

Comment: First, you need to check whether `data.groupStandings[0].active` is changing it's value. Then, you need to define the interval before those statements